# how to print blocks of lines below a matched pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have a logfile to which I regularly append new blocks of text with first line as a tag. All tags start with +. There are no terminating patterns in the blocks. Each block can be 1 or multiple lines.

```
+numbers
23
-87
12
+letters
b
w
a
q
+sentences
line of text
another line of text
+numbers
2
34
+address
line1
line2
line3
+numbers
4
87
```

I want to print all blocks that start with a given tag. For example, for +numbers I want to see:

```
+numbers
23
-87
12
+numbers
2
34
+numbers
4
87
```

or for +address:

```
+address
line1
line2
line3
```

I can do this with awk. But I am looking for a sed solution.

Comment: but that's not really a job for sed, it's a good fit for awk. So, why spend our time finding an awkward, universally *worse* solution using the less appropriate tool? Makes little sense to me.

Comment: "I can remove this screw with a screwdriver, but I am looking for a solution that involves a frozen herring" ;-)

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with one `sed` (this should work with any input: blank lines, consecutive blocks of `+numbers` etc):

```
sed -e '/^+/!{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/^+numbers/!d' logfile
```

How it works:

```
sed '/^+/!{         # if a line doesn't start with a + (so, not a tag)
H                   # append it to hold space and then,
$!d                 # if it's not the last line, delete it (that is, get a
}                   # new input line and restart the cycle); 
x                   # otherwise, exchange buffers and 
/^+numbers/!d'      # if the pattern space doesn't match "^+numbers", delete it
logfile
```

In other words, the "tag" line is saved in the hold buffer when `x` is executed and then the rest of the lines in that block are appended when `H` is executed. When the next "tag" line gets in the pattern space (or on the last line), the buffers are exchanged again, so now the pattern space contains a whole block of lines. It's then only a matter of auto-printing if it starts with `+numbers`

Comment: This is a neat solution, thanks. Would be good if you could provide some explanation. Looks like the code must be a 3-liner to work.

Comment: @elmo - not really, you can write it as a one liner too... I'll edit the answer...

Comment: This exactly what I was after. Many thanks $don_crissti

Answer (score 2):

With two GNU `sed`.

Prerequisite: Your log file does not contain any blank lines.

```
sed 's/^+/\n&/' logfile | sed -n '/+numbers/,/^$/{ /^$/d; p }'
```

Output:

```
+numbers
23
-87
12
+numbers
2
34
+numbers
4
87
```

See `man sed`

Comment: Regrettably the 2nd `sed` strays outside of the IEEE Std 1003.2 (“POSIX.2”) specification. It works fine with GNU sed 4.2.2, but under MacOS 12.6 sed the curly braces cause it to error with "extra characters at the end of p command". Easy to fix with a cleanup grep, though: `sed 's/^+/\n&/' /tmp/k/t | sed -n '/+numbers/,/^$/p' | grep -v '^$'`. The other answers, including the accepted one, work great with the Mac's BSD sed.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
tag=address
sed -n "/^+${tag}/,/^+/ {/^[^+]/p; /^+${tag}/p; }" file
```

This **will** break if the file contains consecutive blocks with the same tag. The range's end regex will consume the tag for the next block.

For comparison, awk commands that won't break in that case

```bash
awk -v tag=address '/^\+/ {p = $0 ~ "\\+" tag "$"} p' file
awk -v tag=numbers -v RS='+' '$1 == tag {printf "+%s", $0}' file
```